# How to re-run the last app exited on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

How many times you've exited an application just to realize that it was still needed?

Web browsers solve this with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> for recently closed tabs. Is there something similar on Windows 7 for recently closed apps?

Comment: I just never close my applications. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be easy enough to make a program that
http://wiredtechnews.com/01/how-to-reopen-your-last-closed-windows-on-windows/
did something like that.
find the link there for UndoClose, I found it originally at Cnet, but cnet has been sneaking in junk to thier downloads, so hopefully this one is closer to the source.

Comment: Works as advertised. Here is a lifehacker article with a video walk-through and comments that suggest alternatives [UndoClose Reopens Windows You’ve Accidentally Closed](http://lifehacker.com/5879003/undoclose-reopens-windows-youve-accidentally-closed)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible to the extend that you want it. And I'm even more sure that this is by design.

The last process you exited by your interaction might not be the last exited process when you perform your magic to restart that last process. I'm sure someone more knowledgeable than me could give you a more detailed explanation why this couldn't work, just let me assure you that it is unlikely that a feature like that could ever work to your satisfaction.